# Automatic Weight Problem - Mesh moves down and armature stays

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, vertex-groups, parent

I'm kinda new with blender so I'm not very familiar with techniques. I just watch and do what they do in Youtube. But this error is something I haven't seen on Youtube yet and I cannot explain what the error is. But it's some thing like this [image: Error] Originally, the mesh is already automatically weighed together with the armature. But, I realized something wrong with the joint positioning, so what I did is I started over by clearing the vertex groups. When I fixed that problem, and clicked "Automatic Weights", it went like that (in the picture). What do I do to fix this. Please help me. I have attached the file below (Thanks for the info.)

[image]

Comment: simply redo the parenting. But if there is a problem somewhere here (in the method, in the mesh or armature or other) that can not be seen clearly in this picture. You should add your blend file in your question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have attached my file :)